# TEGA a handy software that can perform multiple analyses in population genetics

Tags: genetics, population

I was looking for a handy software that can perform multiple analyses in population genetics and found TEGA, looks very good but it is weird why no one cites it since 2020, Is anyone familiar with TEGA?
This software is a web-based tool.

here is it:
https://github.com/darioelias/TEGA